.Net Aspire 9 - To existing Project - Always returns empty 200 reponses
We have an existing .net API project and being intriguied by Aspire decided to try and add it to our solution.  This seems to have worked okay and the dashboard launches with our api listed, however, every request returns with a http 200 repsonse and empty content.
It seems to be handling the endpoints correctly as any incorrect ones are returned with a 401 (which is how it's always worked).
The logs from the project are showing that the api is hit, howver, it doesn't return the correct data.  As a test I've setup this endpoint
app.MapGet("/test", () => { return "test"; }).AllowAnonymous();
this is from the logs:
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7122/test - - -
Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://localhost:7122/test - 200 0 - 6.7426ms

and the postman response:
GET https://localhost:7122/test
200
11 ms
Warning: Unable to verify the first certificate
GET /test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.42.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f8286ede-50e6-4e49-9543-f3b628577b7f
Host: localhost:7122
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2024 12:17:13 GMT
Server: Kestrel

(note the cerificate warning has been there since ever and doesn't normally affect the operation)
I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing, that I haven't configured properly or have made an obvious mistake....
EDIT:
It seems that in the newly added code for AddServiceDefaults there is a resilience strategy added http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();.  Disabling this for now remedies the issue.

As per the edit

It seems that in the newly added code for AddServiceDefaults there is a resilience strategy added http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();. Disabling this for now remedies the issue.

